# Maven fail-safe plugin rerunning individual failing tests that are part of a suite

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm using Maven's failsafe plugin to run integration test suites. The tests themselves are selenium-webdriver tests that use JUnit for the asserts and categories. When I launch an individual test with:
`mvn clean verify -Dfailsafe.rerunFailingTestsCount=N -Pfunctional-test,env-stage -Denvironment=env-stage -DtestBuildNumber=${testBuildNumber} -Dit.test=TestName -Dwebdriver=${browser}  -Dselenium.grid.2.hub=${hub}`
It will rerun failing tests N times.

However if I launch a test suite with that same command it will not rerun failing tests. Is there some way to get rerunFailingTestsCount to work with suites?

Answer (score 1):

What version of failsafe plugin do you use?

Your problem looks like this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1152

> **Option rerunFailingTestsCount silently fails with test suites**
>
> After a test failure (with rerunFailingTestsCount > 0), the
>   JUnit4*Provider.executeWithRerun calls execute again with a list of
>   the failing testMethods, but JUnit4*Provider.execute silently fails to
>   find the requested methods.

Should be fixed in 2.19

Comment: We're using version 2.18.1 so it's good to know it's fixed. Is there an ETA on 2.19 being released? I'm not finding anything beyond 2.18.1 [here.](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven-surefire.git;a=summary)

Comment: No idea when the planned release is, you can try 2.19-SNAPSHOT in the meantime (https://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-testing-development-plugins.html)

Comment: The 2.19 version has now been released.